# String || in indexOf

Tags: java, android, string, indexof

I have a question:

```
int index = abc.indexOf("def"||"ghi");
```

I tried the code above to search "def" or "ghi" in a String "abc". But this doesn't work. There's the error "Operator || cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'java.land.String'".

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I have to ask : what do you expect when your `abc` String contains both `"def"` AND `"ghi"` ? The lower index ? The index of def rather than ghi ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the compiler has stated, the `||` conditional operator is being used incorrectly there.

this is what you want:

```
int index = abc.contains("def") ? abc.indexOf("def"): 
             abc.contains("ghi")? abc.indexOf("ghi"): -1;

if(index != -1 ){
   //do someting
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! This works. I'll check your answer. I can accept it in 6 minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = abc.indexOf("def");
if (index == -1) {
    index = abc.indexOf("ghi");
} else {
    // something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it using the `Matcher` class as follows:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(def)|(ghi)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(abc);

int index;
if (matcher.find()) {
    index = matcher.start();
} else {
    index = -1;
}
```

Basically you compile a certain regex pattern that matches the sequence you want to match. `matcher.find()` will look for the first occurrence of the pattern and if it finds, you can use `matcher.start()` to get the start index of the matched pattern.